# SQL Server - can a fragmented index be worse than no index

Tags: sql-server

If my index is say 80% fragmented and is used in joins can the overall performance be worse than if that index didn't exist? And if so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is too vague to answer consistently, or even to know what you're actually after, but consider this:

A fragmented index means you'll have a lot of actual disk activity compared to the amount of disk activity you'd need for a certain query.

Take a look at `DBCC SHOWCONTIG`
Among other useful information, it shows you a figure for Scan Density. A very low "hit rate" on this can imply that you're doing heaps more IO than you'd need to with a properly maintained index. This could even exceed the amount of IO you'd need to perform a table scan, but it all depends on the size of your objects and your data access pattern.

One area where a poorly maintained (= highly fragmented) index will hurt you double, is that it hurts performance in inserts, updates AND selects. 
With this in mind, it's a pretty common practice for ETL processes to drop indexes before and recreating them after processing large batches of information. In the mean time, they'd only hurt write performance and be too far fragmented to help lookups.

Besides that: it's easy to do index maintenance. I'd recommend deploying Ola Hallengren's index maintenance solution and no longer worry about it.